# Jquery hide and show DIV when radio button is selected

Tags: jquery

I have a small script that should display a div when a radio button is selected.

On page load the Div's are hidden, thats working but when I select radio button "CheckboxGroup1_0" the Divs are not shown. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

My code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#HideDateFromLabel").hide();
    $("#HideDateToLabel").hide();
    $("#HideDateFrom").hide();
    $("#HideDateTo").hide();

    if ( $("#CheckboxGroup1_0").attr('checked')){
        $("#HideDateFromLabel").show();
        $("#HideDateToLabel").show();
        $("#HideDateFrom").show();
        $("#HideDateTo").show();
    }

});

<input name="waterall" type="radio" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" value="0">     
<input name="waterall" type="radio" id="CheckboxGroup1_1"  value="1">
<input name="waterall" type="radio" id="CheckboxGroup1_2"  value="2">

<input name="FromDate" type="text" class="imaindatesel" id="HideDateFrom"  onclick= "scwShow (scwID('FromDate'), event);" value="<? print $FromDateTemp;?>" />

<input name="ToDate" type="text" class="imaindatesel" id="HideDateTo"  onclick= "scwShow (scwID('ToDate'), event);" value="<? print $ToDateTemp;?>"/>
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Wrap the code in the `change` handler of radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `change` event:

```
$("#CheckboxGroup1_0").on('change', function(){
        $("#HideDateFromLabel").show();
        $("#HideDateToLabel").show();
        $("#HideDateFrom").show();
        $("#HideDateTo").show();
});
```

This way when the radio button gets checked it fires the event. Keep in mind that this only fires when the radiobutton is checked, so you want to apply a similar event to other radio buttons to be able to toggle the show/hide

**Update**: as Tushar pointed out in the comment, using Ids is probably a bad idea, as you will end up with a lot of code. My suggestion would be to use classes instead.

Give the inputs you want to show or hide a class i.e.: `.toggleShow`

Now your code becomes a lot cleaner:

```
$("#CheckboxGroup1_0").on('change', function(){
        $(".toggleShow").show();
});
```

Comment: `$("#HideDateFromLabel, #HideDateToLabel, #HideDateFrom, #HideDateTo").show();` And `.trigger('change')` to execute handler on page load.

Comment: OP want to hide the elements on condition when `$("#CheckboxGroup1_0")` is checked.

Comment: @Tushar `if ( $("#CheckboxGroup1_0").attr('checked')){` he shows the elements, it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I got the div's to appear with this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#HideDateFromLabel").hide();
    $("#HideDateToLabel").hide();
    $("#HideDateFrom").hide();
    $("#HideDateTo").hide();

    $("#CheckboxGroup1_0").change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
             $("#HideDateFromLabel").show();
       $("#HideDateToLabel").show();
       $("#HideDateFrom").show();
       $("#HideDateTo").show();
        }
    });

    // if ( $("#CheckboxGroup1_0").attr('checked')){
    //     $("#HideDateFromLabel").show();
    //     $("#HideDateToLabel").show();
    //     $("#HideDateFrom").show();
    //     $("#HideDateTo").show();
    // }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I think you need hide the fields when other radio inputs are selected. Here is my version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  var ids = "#HideDateFromLabel, #HideDateToLabel, #HideDateFrom, #HideDateTo";

  $(ids).hide();

     $('[name="waterall"]').on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).attr('id') == 'CheckboxGroup1_0' ) {
             $(ids).show();
        }
        else{
                $(ids).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

And here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/kasb1bwj/